# Not able to display JSON items in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have a JSON the following JSON file:

```
[
  {
      "pageID":         1,
      "pageName":       "Home Page",
      "pageHead":       "Home Page Title"
  },
  {
      "pageID":         2,
      "pageName":       "Second Page",
      "pageHead":       "2nd Page Title"
  },
  {
      "pageID":         3,
      "pageName":       "Third Page",
      "pageHead":       "3rd Page Title"
  }
]
```

What I am trying to do is display a page takes its title and header from the JSON file.

To do this, I have created the following JS code:

```
var dbApp = angular.module('dbApp', ['ngSanitize']);
dbApp.controller('dbCtrl', function($scope, $http){
            $http.get('pageDB.json').success(function(data) {                   
                $scope.pageContent = data;  
                $scope.pageHeadDB = data[0].pageHead;
                $scope.pageBodyDB = data[0].pageBody;                   
            }); 
        });
```

In the JS code I am using `$scope.pageHeadDB = data[0].pageHead;` using specific index `[1]` but please don't worry about this, later I will make it dynamic.

The following view is supposed to display what I need:

```
<html ng-app="dbApp" ng-controller="dbCtrl">
  <head>
    <title>{{pageHeadDB}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-bind-html="pageBodyDB"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The page displays the data when I use `[0]` which is the first item from the JSON file, but I don't understand why it doesn't work when I make the index `[1]` and/or `[2]`?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Shouldn't you wrap the array in an object? `{content: [...] }`

Comment: Thanks, would you please give me an example? I am sorry I am new to this and I am not really sure how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you see if you do a `console.log(data)` at the top of the `success` function?

Comment: What does data.length give you? Also you're trying to access data[0].pageBody however in the json file you posted this is not an available property.

Comment: Which version of angularJS are you using? `success` call back is deprecated in newer versions. use `then` instead.

Comment: @Mickers the data.length returns the right number which is 3

Comment: @Pete. Angular 1.5.6

Comment: Your script inclusions looks unusual. Angular JS is of version `1.5.6` and angular-sanitize is of `1.2.26`. Why do you omit `https://` for sanitize? How are you testing this? Is it hosted in any server?

Comment: There is no `pageBody` property in the JSON. For the title, instead of changing it in the template, try using `$window.document.title = data[0].pageHead;`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the `<title>` tag problem using this code snippet tool, but here's a solution simplifies some of your logic and works regardless of page number:

```js
angular
  .module('dbApp', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('dbCtrl', dbCtrl);
  
dbCtrl.$inject = ['$window', '$scope', '$http'];
function dbCtrl($window, $scope, $http){
  $scope.page = 0;

  // stubbing ajax call for demo purposes
  // $http.get('pageDB.json').success(function(data) {
  var data = [
    {
      "pageID":         1,
      "pageName":       "Home Page",
      "pageHead":       "Home Page Title"
    },
    {
      "pageID":         2,
      "pageName":       "Second Page",
      "pageHead":       "2nd Page Title"
    },
    {
      "pageID":         3,
      "pageName":       "Third Page",
      "pageHead":       "3rd Page Title"
    }
  ];
  $scope.pageContent = data;
  // }); 
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="dbApp" ng-controller="dbCtrl">
  <head>
    <title>{{ pageContent[page].pageHead }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ pageContent[page].pageHead }}</h1>
    <div ng-bind-html="pageContent[page].pageName"></div>
    <hr/>
    <label>Page:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="page"></input>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```